# How to dynamically load more data when scrolling to the bottom using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use javascript to connect the back-end API. The back-end API needs to be called by GET. After success, the back-end will return an array with some objects in it. I need to add these data to the bottom of the notice_content when scrolling to the bottom . But halfway through the writing, I don’t know how to write it down. It may be that I am still a novice in programming. I don’t know how to implement some parts. I hope I can get your help, thank you. I put the API format given to me by the backend in the question, and attach the current progress of my implementation, thank you everyone.

```
   "route":"/manager/notices_get",
"method":GET,
"param":[
  "notice_type":{interger,string}  //1. General notice 2. Order notice
  "page":{interger,string} 
],
"return":[
  "status":{boolean},
  "notices":[
    {
      id:111,
      title:"my name is james"
    },
    {
      id:222,
      title:"my name is james"
    }
  ]
]
```

Example: Get general notices and the content of the second page /manager/notices_get?page=2¬ice_type=1

```js
// Execute getNotices when scrolling to the bottom
let notice_content = document.querySelector('.notice_content');
let isLoading = false;
notice_content.onscroll = function(){
    if (notice_content.scrollTop + notice_content.clientHeight >= notice_content.scrollHeight && !isLoading) {
        getNotices();
    }
}


// load message function
function getNotices(){
    isLoading = true; 
    let page = 1;
    let noticeType = 1;
    axios.get("/manager/notices_get?page="+page+"&notice_type="+ noticeType)
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

```css
.notice_content{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border:1px solid #222;
}
.message{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="notice_content">
  <div class="message">message1</div>
  <div class="message">message2</div>
  <div class="message">message3</div>
  <div class="message">message4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you basically want to implement an infinite scroll functionality?

Comment: Yes, I hope when scrolling note_ When content is at the bottom, this API will be triggered. Assuming that the API will return two objects in the array in the example, put those two objects in the notice_ At the end of the content block, it looks like infinite loading, but I have tried for more than 3 hours and still don't know how to realize it. I really need your help!

Comment: You can look at https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-infinite-scrolling-with-javascript--cms-37055